# How do I run code if and only if certain items are successfully added to the Cart?

Tags: addtocart, event-observer

I have 4 products with IDs:

```
FreeSilver = 9575
Silver = 9576
Gold = 9577
Platinum = 9578
```

If anyone adds those specific items I want to run different codes to update customer attributes.

is `checkout_cart_product_add_after` EVENT observer the best way to do this?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Let me know if anyone needs to do something similar to this and I'll do my best to help out and respond!

First off I activated my module:
app/etc/Sean_DaysToCart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_DaysToCart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sean_DaysToCart>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then we create the config file:
app/code/local/Sean/DaysToCart/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_DaysToCart>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sean_DaysToCart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sean_testmsg>
                <class>Sean_DaysToCart_Model</class>
            </sean_testmsg>
        </models>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <Sean_DaysToCart_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Sean_DaysToCart_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addtocartEvent</method>
                    </Sean_DaysToCart_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then we create the observer/listener for when item is added to cart:
app/code/local/Sean/DaysToCart/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Sean_DaysToCart_Model_Observer {

    public function addtocartEvent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $Qty = $product->getQty();

        if($productId == 9575 || $productId == 9575){
            $remaining = $customer->getData('silver');
            $total = ($Qty * 365) + $remaining;
            $customer->setData('silver', $total);
            $customer->save();
        }
        elseif($productId == 9577){
            $remaining = $customer->getdata('gold');
            $total = ($Qty * 365) + $remaining;
            $customer->setData('gold', $total);
            $customer->save();
        }
        elseif($productId == 9578){
            $remaining = $customer->getdata('platinum');
            $total = ($Qty * 365) + $remaining;
            $customer->setData('platinum', $total);
            $customer->save();
        }
//        TESTING IN SUCCESS MSG IF PROGRESS WAS MADE
//        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($QTY);

    }
}
```

And it works beautifully! Hopefully you guys can follow along with what I did this method will also work for any functions/code you want to run when items are added to the cart. You can have it run after any item is added or even any specific item like I did :) Happy Coding guys